Unidirectional foreign key columns are not updated on save
I am having issues updating the unidirectional foreign key fields for existing entities. The client sends a PUT request with the full entity data (parent and child entities included), but only the primitive values are updated on save, references for associated entities are not.
I would like to know if there's an annotation or config I'm missing, or I need to implement the functionality myself and if so, how. I'm asking because the existing code suggests this should work out of the box.
For reference, I have an older code base, which was recently upgraded from

Spring Boot: 2.1.3 to 3.3.1
Hibernate: 5.4.1 to 6.5.2.Final

I have the following entities, simplified:
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "PERSON")
// The listener listens for PrePersist and PreUpdate, but does not touch the problematic fields.
@EntityListeners(PersonListener.class)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "birth_country_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_birth_country"))
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private Country birthCountry;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_address",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    )
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    // Other fields omitted for brevity.
}

Both birthCountry and addresses used to have the @LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) annotation.
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Country implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 19)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_country"))
    private Country country;

    @Column(name="street", nullable = false)
    private String street;
}

For both Person and Country I have a simple Rest Repository like below. Address has no repository.
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person", path = "person")
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}


So for example, I have the following Person:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "birthCountry": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "United States"
    },
    "addresses": [{
        "id": 100,
        "country": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "United States"
        },
        "name": "Wall Street"
    }]
}

I receive the following json from the client via PUT when the user selects a new country and modifies the address. This is what I would expect the end result to be:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oliver Smith",
    "birthCountry": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Canada"
    },
    "addresses": [{
        "id": 100,
        "country": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Mexico"
        },
        "name": "Avenida Francisco I. Madero"
    }]
}

SimpleJpaRepository.save is called, but only the change of primitive values are merged. This is the end result in the database:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oliver Smith",
    "birthCountry": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "United States"
    },
    "addresses": [{
        "id": 100,
        "country": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "United States"
        },
        "name": "Avenida Francisco I. Madero"
    }]
}

I can see in the sql debug log that the update statement generated by Hibernate contains id=10 instead of what I received from the client.
Strangely, when I debug the SimpleJpaRepository.save method in IntelliJ and look at the Person entity in the debugger view, I see the new primitive values in related entities with id=null. However if I evaluate an expression querying the same, the code fragment returns old values.

Show how you implemented a service that stores Person.

There is no service or controller class for Person.

There's no error here. According to the HATEOAS style, to change birthCountry in your Person object, you need to send a PUT request to /person/1/birthCountry with a reference to the Country object's address:
PUT /person/1/birthCountry
Content-Type: text/uri-list

/country/11

For more information, see the Spring Data REST.

Unfortunately I had other tasks and could only get back to this recently. I have tried your method and I get "org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException: EntityRepresentationModel not found" error. I have tried adding my api base path as well, or the full url but nothing seems to work. Is there anything else I need to add on the backend?

I have figured out that my Country entity was missing the @RestResource annotation. However, now I get UnsupportedOperation from EmptyRepositoryFactoryInformation, even though there is a Country repository.
